# In Toriko, what animal's skin does Atom show Terry, Kiss and Quinn?

Tags: toriko

In chapter 319 page 3, "Kaka" (Atom in disguise) shows Terry, Kiss, and Quinn a piece of skin or fur of an animal that makes the three scared. What is this skin?

Answer (score 0):

> Unknown creature's skin: ATOM possesses a mysterious piece of skin that appears to have belonged to a creature of tremendous power and vicious bloodthirsty ferocity. Just showing this little piece of skin could invoke paralyzing fear in the hearts of Terry, Kiss, and Quinn.

Taken from [Toriko Wikia](http://toriko.wikia.com/wiki/ATOM_(Nitro)).

So, it seems never to be resolved from what kind of creature this skin was.